# converting data sent into audio signal using microcontroller that suits the application

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

i want to convert text or some numeric data got into speech to make it audible for the listener how do i make it?
Like example :
Say the temp detected at some far place for some process is some "x" data this data got wirelessly near the operator room must be converted into audible voice how do i do this?
Which microcontroller can i use. I have arduino due.

Comment: Search for "text to speech ic": these are a quick integrated solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement the following at a minimum of you want to achieve this with a micro

●Sound files, of the recorded words you need the system to say during announcements.

●External storage to hold them.

●A software algorithm to select the correct files and the correct order

●software interfacing between data input, storage, and audio output.

●Some kind of dac

●some kind of amplifier

●Some kind of speaker

There are things you may want to add, for example file compression to reduce the size of the storage required. Ambient noise sensors to adjust the volume to a sensible level.

If your micro has a built in DAC, you could boost it with an opamp and feed it into an external PA. Alternatively, you may want to use audio specific ics to get better sound quality and an on board power amp.

What is the scope of this project? What other requirements do you have?

Comment: to begin with say i have a keyboard at one end interfaced to microcontroller and ethernet sheild interfaced as well. Now when i press a key that pressed key should be wirelessly transmitted to my mobile and then mobile app will play that text into audio for me.Can i do this way?

Comment: Yes that is possible. your phone is a much better candidate for the data processing and text to speech. The micro then becomes an ethernet port for your sensor.

Comment: As i am pactising with arduino already done programing on 8051 as part of curricular. I just wanted to get started with a project like:I want to turn on lights somwhere else via ethernet and should get audio feedback whether lights are turned on or not as a basic start at this. Now i have no idea about how to start with making text to speech on mobile.